# What is this error in my code? Trying to use userinput for variable and use switch statements

Tags: java

So I was trying to create this simple program were a user enters in a month (1-12) and then using switch statements tell them what month it is based upon what they entered. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class tests{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner monthone = new Scanner(System.in);  
    Double month;
    System.out.println("What is the numerical value of the month? 1-12");
    System.out.print(monthone.nextLine());
    month = monthone.nextDouble();

    switch (month){
    case 1: 
    System.out.println("It's January");
    break;
    case 2: System.out.println("It's Feburary");
    break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("It's March");
    break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("It's April");
    break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("It's May");
    break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("It's June");
    break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("It's July");
    break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("It's August");
    break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("It's September");
    break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("It's October");
    break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("It's November");
    break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println("It's December");
    break;
    default:
    System.out.println("I Don't know what month it is..");
    break;
    }

 }
}
```

Can anybody provide a solution or help? I tried using a Int for my variable as well but that failed... :s
(Please detail answers.. I am here to learn not to be given an answer in a quick reply.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've defined month as a Double.

```
Double month;
```

However, you can only switch on the following types:

- byte (and its wrapper, Byte)
- short (and its wrapper, Short)
- char (and its wrapper, Character)
- int (and its wrapper, Integer)
- Enum Types
- String

Therefore,

```
switch (month) {
```

is syntactically incorrect and will cause a compilation error.

A few other things are not right:

[image]

Here's the revised code:

public static void main(String args[]){

```
Scanner monthone = new Scanner(System.in);

int month;
System.out.println("What is the numerical value of the month? 1-12");    
//System.out.print(monthone.nextLine());    
month = monthone.nextInt();

switch (month){
case 1: 
System.out.println("It's January");
break;
case 2: System.out.println("It's Feburary");
break;
```

Comment: You can also switch on an `enum`.

Comment: Yup, missed that and added all as well.

Comment: Great reply, very in-depth. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're also consuming an extra line of input after prompting the user for a value.

```
System.out.println("What is the numerical value of the month? 1-12");
System.out.print(monthone.nextLine()); // Remove this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your month an int, remove this line: `System.out.print(monthone.nextLine());`, and change `nextDouble` to `nextInt`.

Comment: Great it worked! Can you explain why I didn't need                                           System.out.print(monthone.nextLine());

Comment: That statement would read what was entered on the keyboard and then print it out. So when the user enters the month it would be printed out and then your program would wait for another input when it got here: month = monthone.nextDouble();